# pjax or client side MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, backbone.js, pjax

i have to start a new project, a webapp with lots of forms and screens and i really don't know which technology fit best. The application is an ERP like app, with very few animations and lot of forms. The goal is to reduce at minimum reloads and waiting time, it has to be as close as possible to a normal desktop app (a lot of work to look like a marvelous VB6 app :-)

On the one hand we have client side MVC (backbone). It's cool to have all the code running on client but in my mind this implies repetition of lot of code (for example all models definitions) from server (PHP + Fuel). Sure once loaded all the informations task like paginations or grid work without any delay but it also present some problems of synchronization (other users can change data and i have to manually invalidate data on client).

On the other hand we have pjax. The idea is to make all the templating and so on on server, just implement a logic to return the page without the frame for pjax request or full page on new requests. No code duplication, very simple client side.

I've read the the story [from basecamp](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3112-how-basecamp-next-got-to-be-so-damn-fast-without-using-much-client-side-ui) and [from twitter](http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/05/improving-performance-on-twittercom.html) and both the point make sense to me. You can't relay on visitor computer (features, performance ...)

The more i think about it the mode i like pjax over MVC, but maybe i'm missing something. Which  are the MVC advantages over pjax or pjax disadvantages over Client side MVC ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Backbone.js is good for heavy, single page web apps that never truly post back, but have lots of ajaxian things going on, interdependent cascading dropdowns, etc. It has a very good API for events and collections. If you have plentiful client side javascript, it can be a helpful way to organize it.  It is opinionated in the sense that it expects your server-side architecture to be RESTful by default, and you have to make some effort to use it for non RESTful APIs.

The project I'm working on is an ERP web app as well, with asp.net MVC on the server-side. I've learned that Backbone (with handlebars as the templating system), and .net mvc really don't play together that well.  If you go Backbone, you really have to go full-hog (controller methods serve up json, that's it).  On pages in this app that are more or less 'normal' web pages with some forms, Backbone is the wrong choice.

I just googled pjax for the first time, so I've basically just read the short description at the top of the page, but I suspect that might be the way to go for your scenario, in keeping with Keep It Simple Silly principles.